# perl automate installation of SAX module

Tags: perl, shell, automation, cpan

One of my perl script uses XML::SAX module. As this script would be run from any system on the network, I am working on writing a shell script which would automatically download the module and install it in a private lib.

The script works fine but in the middle of it, this question comes up:

```
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite XML::SAX::Base 1.05 not found. We have 1.04.
Do you want XML::SAX to alter ParserDetails.ini? [Y]
```

And the program waits for user input. Is there any way to skip this? 
These scripts will be run as remote jobs and the people running the jobs aren't going to be looking at the console very often.

Also, I tried working with expect, but I get the error 'spawn' not found. So I'm thinking it's not a part of the standard shell utility.

Please advise if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your cpan client to use `follow` as the `prerequisites_policy`. In the cpan shell, enter:

```
o conf prerequisites_policy follow
o conf commit
```

Comment: This is not seem to be an option since this script could be run from any random host within the network.

Comment: @manpreetbhamba: You can send the two lines to the standard input of `cpan`, or you can change the config file in a different way.